# Algorithm to do a summation over a column with random selection of data from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([IdeaNr] int, [SubmitterName] varchar(4), [SubmitterDepartment] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([IdeaNr], [SubmitterName], [SubmitterDepartment])
VALUES
    (1, 'Joe', 'Org1'),
    (1, 'Bill', 'Org2'),
    (1, 'Kate', 'Org1'),
    (1, 'Tom', 'Org3'),
    (2, 'Sue', 'Org2'),
    (3, 'Bill', 'Org2'),
    (3, 'Fred', 'Org1'),
    (4, 'Ted', 'Org3'),
    (4, 'Kate', 'Org1'),
    (4, 'Hank', 'Org3')
;
```

I want get the following result from a query:

```
IdeaNr  SubmitterCount   SubmitterRndName   SubmitterRndDepartment
1       4                Joe or ...         Org1 (if Joe)
2       1                Sue                Org2
3       2                Bill or ...        Org2 (if Bill)
4       3                Ted or ...         Org3 (if Ted)
```

I have tried a lot of things with all kind of JOINs of Table1 with itself, derived tables and GROUP BY, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(IdeaNr) AS SubmitterCount,IdeaNr,SubmitterName,SubmitterDepartment
FROM Table1
GROUP BY IdeaNr,SubmitterName,SubmitterDepartment
```

I think the problem is to create an algorithm that takes just the first (or a random) name and department appearing in a group of IdeaNr. It is absolutely clear that you can get to misleading interpretations of that kind of data, e. g.:

- Org1 has 2 Ideas
- Org2 has 1 Idea
- Org3 has 1 Idea

But this kind of "wrong averaging" is OK for the task. Can you help?

**EDIT:** The expected result evolved during the discussion. The desired result changed to:

```
IdeaNr  SubmitterCount   SubmitterRndName   SubmitterRndDepartment
1       4                Joe, Bill, ...     GroupIdea
2       1                Sue                Org2
3       2                Bill, Fred         GroupIdea
4       3                Ted, ...           GroupIdea
```

Comment: I corrected third line in the expected result, because I think you mistyped it. Please edit it further if I did it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ([IdeaNr] int, [SubmitterName] varchar(4), [SubmitterDepartment] varchar(4));
INSERT INTO @Table1([IdeaNr], [SubmitterName], [SubmitterDepartment])
VALUES
    (1, 'Joe', 'Org1'),
    (1, 'Bill', 'Org2'),
    (1, 'Kate', 'Org1'),
    (1, 'Tom', 'Org3'),
    (2, 'Sue', 'Org2'),
    (3, 'Bill', 'Org2'),
    (3, 'Fred', 'Org1'),
    (4, 'Ted', 'Org3'),
    (4, 'Kate', 'Org1'),
    (4, 'Hank', 'Org3');

SELECT x.IdeaNr
      ,Count(x.IdeaNr)
      ,MAX(Submitter.SubmitterName) AS SubmitterRndName
      ,MAX(Submitter.SubmitterDepartment) AS SubmitterRndDepartment
FROM @Table1 AS x 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 SubmitterName, SubmitterDepartment
    FROM @Table1 AS y 
    WHERE y.IdeaNr=x.IdeaNr
) AS Submitter
GROUP BY x.IdeaNr
```

There is one more idea, don't know if you could need this:

```
SELECT x.IdeaNr
      ,Count(x.IdeaNr)
      ,STUFF(
            (
            SELECT ', ' + y.SubmitterName --maybe with DISTINCT
            FROM @Table1 AS y
            WHERE y.IdeaNr=x.IdeaNr
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,2,'') AS AllSubmitters
      ,STUFF(
            (
            SELECT ', ' + z.SubmitterDepartment --maybe with DISTINCT
            FROM @Table1 AS z
            WHERE z.IdeaNr=x.IdeaNr
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,2,'') AS AllDepartments
FROM @Table1 AS x 
GROUP BY x.IdeaNr
```

This comes back with

```
IdeaNr                  AllSubmitters              AllDepartments
1           4           Joe, Bill, Kate, Tom       Org1, Org2, Org1, Org3
2           1           Sue                        Org2
3           2           Bill, Fred                 Org2, Org1
4           3           Ted, Kate, Hank            Org3, Org1, Org3
```

EDIT: Following your idea from the last comment:

```
SELECT x.IdeaNr
      ,COUNT(x.IdeaNr)
      ,STUFF(
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + y.SubmitterName 
            FROM @Table1 AS y
            WHERE y.IdeaNr=x.IdeaNr
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,2,'') AS AllSubmitters
      ,CASE WHEN COUNT(x.IdeaNr)=1 THEN (SELECT TOP 1 z.SubmitterDepartment FROM @Table1 AS z WHERE z.IdeaNr=x.IdeaNr)
            ELSE 'GroupIdea' END AS Departments
FROM @Table1 AS x 
GROUP BY x.IdeaNr
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your both examples work well. For the first program: I've never heard about CROSS APPLY before. I found some explanation here, comparing JOIN and CROSS APPLY: http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/

Comment: @Bebass, Pleased to help you. CROSS APPLY is great for row based access, especially connected with XML and functions. One hint: You could easily change the second approach to `Joe (Org1), Bill (Org2), Kate (Org1), Tom (Org3)` and so on. If this is what you need please vote up and/or mark as accepted, thx!

Comment: The second program is very advanced for me ;) But it's very a nice trick to concatenate multiple rows of data into a single string! But this idea brings me to another idea: for the column [AllDepartments] it would be sufficient to have an entry 'GroupIdea' istead of all department names. This would facilitate a further evaluation in Excel because you just have one more element in that column and not many recombinations of elements.

Comment: @Bebass, that means, you want to read the Department's name when there's only one and the expression "GroupIdea" if there are many? Same with Submitter's name?

Comment: For the column [AllSubmitters] your solution from the second program is very nice (getting a list of names separated by a comma). For the column [AllDepartments] i want to read the department's name when there's only one and the expression "GroupIdea" if there are many (like you wrote). I will try to adapt your code to this idea.

Comment: @Bebass, added after EDIT, bottom of my answer. Please vote up and or mark as accepted if helpful, thx!

Comment: Great, it works perfectly! Thank you for developing this solution with me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read more about this topic search for `top-N-per-group`. In SQL Server it is easy to do using `CROSS APPLY`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbf50/1/0)

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        IdeaNr
        ,COUNT(*) AS SubmitterCount
    FROM @Table1
    GROUP BY IdeaNr
)
SELECT
    CTE.IdeaNr
    ,CTE.SubmitterCount
    ,CA.SubmitterName
    ,CA.SubmitterDepartment
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            T.SubmitterName
            ,T.SubmitterDepartment
        FROM @Table1 AS T
        WHERE T.IdeaNr = CTE.IdeaNr

        --ORDER BY T.SubmitterName
        --ORDER BY T.SubmitterDepartment
        --ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)

    ) AS CA
ORDER BY CTE.IdeaNr;
```

If you don't put any `ORDER BY` in the `CROSS APPLY` part the server will pick one "random" row. It is not random as such, but results may be the same or may differ when you run this query several times. In practice, results will most likely differ if you create or drop indexes on the table, but if the table is large they may differ every time the query runs.

If you want to pick some specific row for each `IdeaNr`, then use `ORDER BY` Name or Department or some ID, etc.

If you want to pick a really random row, then `ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)`.

I get the following result without any `ORDER BY` when I use table variable for this test without any indexes:

```
IdeaNr    SubmitterCount    SubmitterName    SubmitterDepartment
1         4                 Joe              Org1
2         1                 Sue              Org2
3         2                 Bill             Org2
4         3                 Ted              Org3
```

It looks as if it picked the "first" row for each `IdeaNr` in the order as they were added to the table. But, don't be fooled, the order is not guaranteed without explicit `ORDER BY`. If you want to get the first row for each `IdeaNr` in the order as they were added to the table, you need to store information about this order somehow. For example, add a column `ID int IDENTITY` to the table that would increment automatically as new rows are added and then you can use it like this `ORDER BY ID DESC` to get guaranteed results.

Play with SQL Fiddle to see how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I used SQLite a lot and so i've been avoiding CTEs until now. But it seems to me a very useful concept. I've found some introduction here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/ And even SQLite seems to have it now: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: I also like your suggestion with ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)!

Comment: @Bebass, CTE makes queries more readable. In this case it is possible to  put that `SELECT ... GROUP BY` as a nested query into the main one. But, it looks like your question has evolved and you are after a different result, so this answer becomes not really relevant.

Comment: Yes the question has evolved. I put a comment about the change in the question. Nevertheless thank you very much for your detailed answer - it will encourage me to learn more about CTEs.